# Avoid nested for with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to implement a generic operation on the elements of some np 2D arrays (A,B,C). In pseudo-code

```
for i in A.height:
    for j in A.width:
        A[i,j] = f(B[i,j],C[i,j])
```

where f() is concatenating the bits of the two variables by means of struct.pack(), struct.unpack()

```
            x = struct.pack('2B', B[i, j], C[i, j])
            y = struct.unpack('H', x)
```

This code takes a really long time to execute (0.25 secs for 640*480 matrices ... maybe is normal yet I could use something faster ), so I was wondering if anybody could suggest me some pythonic way of achieving the same result which could also improve the performance

Comment: Depends on what `f()` does. You could try using threads or multiprocessing.

Comment: Not really sure how you expect anyone to answer without any knowledge of what `f` is doing, how big your data is, or what "really long time to execute" actually means.

Comment: Could you modify `f` to take advantage of [broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc)?

Comment: It's not the nesting itself that's slow but rather calling your function 300,000 times.  The `struct` code is already compiled (builtin).  Is there a way of getting those values without ordinary whole array math? Add, time, modulus?

Answer (score 1):

Your function:

```
In [310]: def foo(a,b):
     ...:     x = struct.pack('2B', a,b)
     ...:     return struct.unpack('H',x)[0]
```

`np.vectorize` is a convenient way of broadcasting arrays.  It passes scalar values to the functions.  It does not speed up the code (related `frompyfunc` may give a 2x speed up relative to plain iteration)

```
In [311]: fv = np.vectorize(foo)
In [312]: fv(np.arange(5)[:,None],np.arange(10))
Out[312]: 
array([[   0,  256,  512,  768, 1024, 1280, 1536, 1792, 2048, 2304],
       [   1,  257,  513,  769, 1025, 1281, 1537, 1793, 2049, 2305],
       [   2,  258,  514,  770, 1026, 1282, 1538, 1794, 2050, 2306],
       [   3,  259,  515,  771, 1027, 1283, 1539, 1795, 2051, 2307],
       [   4,  260,  516,  772, 1028, 1284, 1540, 1796, 2052, 2308]])
```

I can replicate those values with a simple math expression on the same arrays:

```
In [313]: np.arange(5)[:,None]+np.arange(10)*256
Out[313]: 
array([[   0,  256,  512,  768, 1024, 1280, 1536, 1792, 2048, 2304],
       [   1,  257,  513,  769, 1025, 1281, 1537, 1793, 2049, 2305],
       [   2,  258,  514,  770, 1026, 1282, 1538, 1794, 2050, 2306],
       [   3,  259,  515,  771, 1027, 1283, 1539, 1795, 2051, 2307],
       [   4,  260,  516,  772, 1028, 1284, 1540, 1796, 2052, 2308]])
```

This probably only works for limited ranges of values, but it gives an idea of how you can properly 'vectorize' calculations in `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what 'f' does... Not sure if this is what you mean

```
b = np.arange(3*4).reshape(3,4)
c = np.arange(3*4).reshape(3,4)[::-1]

b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

c
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3]])

def f(b, c):
    """some function"""
    a = b + c
    return a

a = f(b, c)
a 
array([[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14]])
```